# Speech to text conversion using speech_recognition Python library gives error

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have written a python code to convert speech to text and eventually I would like to save the output in a file.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r= sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile("c://Akash//male.wav") as source:    
    audio= r.listen(source)
try:
    print("system predicts"+r.recognize_google(audio))
except Exception:
    print("something wrong")
```

Above code always takes me to exception part and prints "something wrong". 
Also I would need help on saving the output to a text file.
Edit 1:
Error 
[image]

Edit 2:
I tried this by using audio file from Azure Data Lake and it worked once. But after that it did not work. Not sure why the same code when I executed again, it did not work.

[image]

Comment: use either '\\' or '/'.

Comment: this did not help..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that problem might be caused by path `"c://Akash//male.wav"`, possibly slashes - if you are using `Windows` operating system try changing it `"c:/Akash/male.wav"` or `"c:\\Akash\\male.wav"`.
If neither helps, please replace 4 lines of your `try`-`except` with single line

```
print("system predicts"+r.recognize_google(audio))
```

and write us what is in error message.

EDIT: It raised `UnknownValueError`, after I examined example of usage of `speech_recognition` named [audio_transcribe.py](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/audio_transcribe.py) I think this simply means that `Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio`.

Comment: I did try with \\ but that did not help. Also replaced last 4 lines with the above but it gives error.  Adding screenshot of the error in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the reading of the file here :
("c://Akash//male.wav")

you can change it to :
(r"c://Akash//male.wav")
where here you need to include you are reading the file